# Schedule auto shutdown and restart on specific days - Express Server

Tags: node.js, express, scheduling

I would like to configure my Express Server to stop automatically at 3:00 pm on Saturdays and restart at 4:00am on Mondays. How could I do this ?

Also, I would like it to restart automatically if it crashes without waiting for file changes (I'm using nodemon).

Answer (score 0):

You can write scripts that starts and kills the server and add them in a cronjob service, for example cron in linux.

For example: say script `start.sh` and `stop.sh` are in home directory that start and stop your server.

Add these lines to crontab file:

```
00 15 * * 6 ~/start.sh
00 04 * * 1 ~/stop.sh
```

First line: 3 PM on all Saturdays
Second line: 4 AM on all Mondays

Reference: [Link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)